# when unmarshalling list data,can jaxb requires defining just one class

Tags: java, jaxb

Have a xml data like

```
<Items><Item><name>"test1"</name></Item><Item><name>"test2"</name></Item></Items>
```

Looks like jaxb cannot unmashall this when defining only Item class. It requires me to define both Items and Item class. Is there any way to just define one class to handle list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAXB requires a root object.  For more information on JAXB and Lists see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/jaxb-collection-properties.html